# Laying out forms in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, forms, xaml, c#-5.0

I refer to mainly tabular forms, with columns of labels and corresponding input controls. In HTML we can use `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or my favourite, `<dl>`, to couple labels and inputs making them integral input devices. In WPF I can find (I am very new) nothing but a `Grid` control with two columns, one for label, and one for input. Often several of these monstrosities are needed to complete a form layout.

Is there no integral functionality in WPF for form layout? It was designed for Windows UI windows, a great, great many of which are simple forms, not fancy graphics or animations.

Comment: Start with it is not a form in WPF.  Grid?

Comment: A form is a collection of input and display fields, whatever you use to semanticise their positions them and to lay them out.

Comment: What part of WPF does not have a form is not clear?  Learn the names of the controls.

Comment: Oh @Blam, get a life.

Comment: You are supposed to be a profession developer and ask a very basic question using incorrect terminology.  You state you are learning MVVM and don't even know basic terms?  Get a grip.

Answer (score 1):

Put your controls in a Grid container. That should allow you the tabular layout you're looking for.

Comment: I'm looking for more than a tabular layout. I'm looking e.g. for a layout that links a label to its input control, more than just being on the same grid row. In web stuff, we have much richer forms tools.

Answer (score 1):

There are several containers at your disposal. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514628(v=vs.90).aspx) is a list explaining each one. The [Grid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.90).aspx) container is what you're probably interested in. You're able to specify RowDefintions and ColumnDefinitions to construct a grid to place other controls.

Comment: Was the `Grid` I meant when I said table. It's extremely clumsy.

Comment: It's more than possible to create your own UserControl that contains a Label and TextBox that can encapsulate the logic you're looking for.  The built-in containers and controls are building blocks. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086895/wpf-label-to-textbox) is a simple way to implement this.