# Move label content into a textbox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have currently got some text in a label, I am trying to transfer it into a textbox. I have tried this method but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Any suggestions?
[WPF Label to TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086895/wpf-label-to-textbox)

XAML

```
    <Label x:Name="TotalNumberInputted" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="122,282,0,0" Content="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="35" Background="{x:Null}"  />


    <TextBox Height="23" Margin="187,282,554,0" Name=" TotalNumberTextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextChanged="TotalNumberTextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

CS

```
    string LocalLabel = "";
    string LocalTextBox = "";

    public string Label
    {
        get { return LocalLabel; }
        set
        {
            LocalLabel = value;
            TotalNumberInputted.Content = value;
        }
    }

    public string TextBox
    {
        get { return LocalTextBox; }
        set
        {
            LocalTextBox = value;
            NewQuantity.Text = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your code so we can fix it together.

Comment: I have added it in

Comment: Thank you. But still it's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Please help to understand you. How does the code snippets connect?

Comment: In essence, I get the user to input their chosen number on a previous page, which is then shown in the label. I am trying to get that number into a text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use bindings ([Tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm), [MSDN Data Binding Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview))

```
<StackPanel>
  <Label x:Name="TotalNumberLabel" Content="some content" />

  <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=TotalNumberLabel, Path=Content}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Now when setting the Label's content the TextBox will update automatically.